# Multiple checkboxes with results stored in same DB field - cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

As part of a CakePHP (2.2) app I'm writing in my user controllers admin_add() I need to have a series of check boxes relating to what documents a user can access. However, I need the results of each check box to go into the same DB field.

For example, say you had 3 checkboxes with the values 1, 2 & 3 - if all three were ticked they would go into the same db field as the following string:

`1,2,3`

How can I do this?

I know this is messy and normally I'd have this controlled by ACL but the need has arisen to do this differently (mainly due to the way the previous incarnation of this app was written and other factors outside of my control).

Thanks in advance

Update re David's comment **

I've got a slightly amended version of your suggested code as below:

```
if(isset($this->request->data['User'])){
    foreach($this->request->data['User']['manuals'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == 1) {
        $field .= $key .", ";
    }
}
    $this->request->data['User']['manuals'] = rtrim($field, ', ');
}
```

This code works in fine the controller add() function (writes the correct string to the db as I wanted) but produced the following error when done in the beforeSave() model function

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
```

The SQL statement that causes the above error is :

```
SQL Query: INSERT INTO `cakeapp`.`users` (`webforms_email`, `manuals_email`, `user_status_id`, `view_uat`, `username`, `password`, `forename`, `surname`, `company`, `position`, `version_numbers_id`, `support_case_reference`, `support_web_password`, `group_id`, `manuals`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES ('1', '1', 2, '1', 't800@cyberdyne.com', '48e813c14688aff66054d1f1eb93c02d977648c1', 'T800', '101', 'Cyberdyne', 'terminator', 1, '', '', 14, Array, '2012-11-21 12:28:33', '2012-11-21 12:28:33')
```

The issue seems to be with the Array its trying to insert rather than the contents of the array. Any ideas? Thanks again for your help.

As requested -

```
public function beforeSave() {

    // Added this if for cases when user being saved but password isnt set 
    if (isset($this->data['User']['password'])) {       
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
        return true;
    }


    if(isset($this->request->data['User'])){
        foreach($this->request->data['User']['manuals'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == 1) {
                $field .= $key .", ";
            }
        }
        $this->request->data['User']['manuals'] = rtrim($field, ', ');
    }


}
```

Debug of $this->request->data on add():

```
array(
'User' => array(
    'password' => '*****',
    'username' => 'test@test.com',
    'forename' => 'James',
    'surname' => 'Jacobs',
    'company' => 'Company name',
    'position' => 'Web dev',
    'version_numbers_id' => '1',
    'support_case_reference' => '',
    'support_web_password' => '',
    'webforms_email' => '0',
    'manuals_email' => '0',
    'group_id' => '14',
    'user_status_id' => '1',
    'view_uat' => '1',
    'manuals' => array(
        (int) 36 => '1',
        (int) 31 => '1',
        (int) 32 => '1',
        (int) 33 => '1',
        (int) 34 => '0',
        (int) 35 => '0',
        (int) 37 => '0',
        (int) 38 => '0',
        (int) 39 => '0',
        (int) 40 => '0',
        (int) 41 => '0',
        (int) 30 => '0',
        (int) 29 => '0',
        (int) 24 => '0',
        (int) 25 => '0',
        (int) 26 => '0',
        (int) 27 => '0',
        (int) 28 => '0',
        (int) 47 => '0',
        (int) 48 => '0',
        (int) 49 => '0',
        (int) 118 => '0',
        (int) 117 => '0',
        (int) 94 => '0',
        (int) 88 => '0',
        (int) 51 => '0',
        (int) 50 => '0',
        (int) 46 => '0',
        (int) 45 => '0',
        (int) 9 => '0',
        (int) 6 => '0',
        (int) 5 => '0',
        (int) 10 => '0',
        (int) 4 => '0',
        (int) 44 => '0',
        (int) 7 => '0',
        (int) 43 => '0',
        (int) 42 => '0',
        (int) 125 => '0',
        (int) 124 => '0',
        (int) 127 => '0',
        (int) 129 => '0',
        (int) 130 => '0',
        (int) 126 => '0',
        (int) 131 => '0',
        (int) 132 => '0',
        (int) 133 => '0',
        (int) 134 => '0',
        (int) 135 => '0',
        (int) 136 => '0',
        (int) 137 => '0',
        (int) 168 => '0',
        (int) 123 => '0',
        (int) 128 => '0',
        (int) 97 => '0',
        (int) 91 => '0',
        (int) 101 => '0',
        (int) 100 => '0',
        (int) 98 => '0',
        (int) 92 => '0',
        (int) 95 => '0',
        (int) 93 => '0',
        (int) 74 => '0',
        (int) 120 => '0',
        (int) 73 => '0',
        (int) 75 => '0',
        (int) 76 => '0',
        (int) 72 => '0',
        (int) 122 => '0',
        (int) 119 => '0',
        (int) 175 => '0',
        (int) 174 => '0',
        (int) 173 => '0',
        (int) 172 => '0',
        (int) 171 => '0',
        (int) 170 => '0',
        (int) 169 => '0',
        (int) 176 => '0'
    ),
    'filename' => array(
        'name' => '',
        'type' => '',
        'tmp_name' => '',
        'error' => (int) 4,
        'size' => (int) 0
    )
)
```

)

Comment: I've no idea why this isn't working, it looks totally fine. `var_dump($field)` at the end of your `beforeSave()` and make sure it's not an array, as it looks like it is for some reason. Either that, or it's not overwriting the request data properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was doing this I would use a model callback function.

In your `User` model, I'd create a `beforeSave()`. Your implementation might differ, but hopefully you get the idea from the below quick example.

```
public function beforeSave(){
  if(isset($this->data['User']){
    foreach($this->data['User']['documents'] as $doc){
       $field .= $doc .", ";
    }
    $this->data['User']['allowed_docs'] = rtrim($field, ', ');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - re the view, I take it I need to manually build the inputs as opposed to using form helper? I'll just set the name as [documents][id]?

Also what the benefit of doing it in a beforeSave as opposed to in the add() function?

Comment: Use the form helper to create your inputs, otherwise you'll spend forever trying to organise your array properly.  
You are dealing with changing data, data goes in the model, not in the controller. "Thin controllers, fat models". The benefit is that it's correct MVC.

Comment: Sorry - I'm getting the following error - relating to the model code:

`Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'`

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to update your question, with a `var_dump()` of your `$this->request->data` and your `Model::beforeSave()`